# Using a truth table to prove or disprove $¬(P\vee (Q\wedge R))=(¬P)\wedge (¬Q\vee ¬R)$ and $¬(P\wedge (Q\vee R))=¬P\vee (¬Q\vee ¬R)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

***This question was taken from the MIT OCW Math for Computer Science course.***

Use a truth table to prove or disprove the following statements:

a) $¬(P\vee (Q\wedge R))=(¬P)\wedge (¬Q\vee ¬R)$

b) $¬(P\wedge (Q\vee R))=¬P\vee (¬Q\vee ¬R)$

**What I got thus far:**

a) $\\
\begin{array}{c|c}
P & Q &  R & Q \land R & P\vee (Q\wedge R) & ¬(P\vee (Q\wedge R)) & ¬P & ¬Q\vee ¬R & (¬P)\wedge (¬Q\vee ¬R)   \\ \hline
T & T & T & T & T & F & F & F & F \\
T & T & F & F & T & F & F & T & F \\ 
T & F & T & F & T & F & F & T & F \\
T & F & F & F & T & F & F & T & F \\
F & T & T & T & T & F & T & F & F \\
F & T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & F & F & T & T & T & T \\
F & F & F & F & F & T & T & T & T \\
\end{array}$

So, according to this table, it seems that these two statements are equivalent; however, when I plug these two entire statements into Wolfram Alpha, the result is: [image]

What is going on here? Did I make a careless mistake somewhere?

---

b) $\\
\begin{array}{c|c}
P & Q &  R & Q\vee R & P\wedge (Q\vee R) & ¬(P\wedge (Q\vee R)) & ¬P & ¬Q\vee ¬R & ¬P\vee (¬Q\vee ¬R)   \\ \hline
T & T & T & T & T & F & F & F & F \\
T & T & F & T & T & F & F & T & T \\ 
T & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & T \\
T & F & F & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T & F & T & T & F & T \\
F & T & F & T & F & T & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & T & F & T & T & T & T \\
F & F & F & F & F & T & T & T & T \\
\end{array}$

The answer to b), in accordance with my truth table seems to be that $¬(P\wedge (Q\vee R))\neq ¬P\vee (¬Q\vee ¬R)$. Wolfram Alpha's result seems to confirm this: 
[image]

Comment: it seems wolfram is not taking into account the first "not" when the sentence is expressed in the result

Comment: @LuisVera Are my truth tables and answers are correct?

Comment: yes, I only checked (a) but is correct

Comment: What WolframAlpha is doing is to negate the statement that you put $\neg$ in front of. And since the statement is an equality, the result of the negation is an inequality. What WolframAlpha is doing is not to prove or disprove anything, so it really has nothing to do with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @mrp

Are my truth tables and answers correct? In addition, is there a way to verify my answers with Wolfram Alpha? What if I entered: "Is $¬(P\vee (Q\wedge R))$ equivalent to $(¬P)\wedge (¬Q\vee ¬R)$. What exactly do you mean by "since the statement is an equality, the result of the negation is an inequality"? From what I understand, after constructing the first truth table, the first statement is an equality, negation sign included, no?

Answer (score 1):

Your truth tables and answers are correct and yes there is a way to verify that.
If P and Q are equal then $(P\vee ¬Q)$ would be tautology.
[image]